# Infinity to a power less than 1 and larger than zero

Tags: limits

What is infinity to the power 0.1 equal to ?

for example , if we have the following limit 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{0.1}$$

Comment: The limit is  $\infty$.

Comment: $n^b$ increases without limit as $n$ increases without limit, when $b >0$.   You have $\log(n)$ unbounded above, as is $b \log(n)$, and so is $n^b= e^{b \log(n)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the extended real numbers, $\infty^x = \infty$ whenever $x > 0$.

And furthermore, exponentiation is continuous there. So if

- $\lim_n f(n) = \infty$
- $\lim_n g(n) =  L$  with $L > 0$

then  you have

$$ \lim_n f(n)^{g(x)} = \left(\lim_n f(n)\right)^{\lim_n g(n)} = \infty^L = \infty $$

---

For completeness, $\infty^x = 0$ whenever $x < 0$, and exponentiation is continuous there as well.

The remaining case $\infty^0$ is undefined. This fact is closely related to the notion of an "indeterminate form".

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the definition of limit towards infinity:

$$\forall N\in \mathbb{R},\quad \exists M\in\mathbb{R},\quad n>M ~~\text{then}~~  n^{0.1}>N  $$

How to select M?

$$M=N^{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $M>0$, if $n>M^{10}$, then $n^{1/10}>M$. Hence the limit is $\infty$.